# Is adding project root directory to sys.path a good practice?

Tags: python, bash, coding-style

I have a question about adding project path to python, for facilitating `import` effort.

## Situation

When I write code in Python, I usually add necessary path to `sys.path` by using

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/dir/") # almost every `.py` need this
```

Sometimes, when my project gets bigger with many levels of directories, this approach seems bulky and error-prone (especially when I re-organize my files)

Recently, I start using a bash script (located at project root directory) that adding the `sys.path.append` with project root argument to `.py` file in the project. With this approach, I hardly have to manually care about importing a module.

## Question

My question is: Is that a good practice? I find it convenient for myself, compared to my old method, but since the bash script is a separated file, I need 2 command to run any script in my project (one for the bash and one for the `.py`). I can include the command calling `.py` to the bash, but it far less flexible than directly call it from terminal.

Really want to hear some advices! Thanks in advance. Any suggestion will be gratefully appreciated!

Comment: This is generally _not_ good practice. It's generally not necessary, because the path to the script is already added to `sys.path` automatically. But meanwhile, for distribution/deployment, you almost always want to create a `pip install`-able package with `setuptools`, a distributable virtualenv, an installer package via PyInstaller/etc., a Docker image with your app pre-installed, or something else, while for local development, if you don't want to install `--inplace`, you probably want a virtualenv with a path set up.

Comment: Also, you usually shouldn't have scripts scattered all over the project—definitely not inside packages, but usually even if they aren't. If you need a ton of scripts, you should look at creating either `-m`-runnable modules, or `setuptools`-generated entry-point scripts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems you misunderstood my question. What I am asking is instead of adding multiple different `sys.path.append` to different `.py`, I can add the **project root** to `sys.path` to almost every `.py` and do importing modules correspond to that added **project root**. Note that I'm not familiar with distribution/deployment a package, so maybe I am the one who misunderstand here :D

Comment: If almost every `.py` file needs this, then you're probably doing something wrong. (Possibly something _very_ wrong, like putting scripts in the middle of packages, but possibly not.) The best answer is usually to rearrange your project so you don't need that. That's not _always_ true, but without any specifics, it's impossible to know whether you're facing an exception to that general rule.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is generally not good practice to use manipulate `sys.path` within a python library or program. You should add the relevant paths to the [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) in the calling environment for your python program:

```
PYTHONPATH="/path/to/other/projects/directory:$PYTHONPATH" python ...
```

or

```
export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/other/projects/directory:$PYTHONPATH"
python ...
```

This allows you to easily manipulate the paths that your program or library will search for dependencies easily without modifying your code.

It is also very easy to manage this in your personal development environment by modifying your [`bashrc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work) or in your production environments in your `init` script (or other wrapper script) and provides you with one place to update each time you add or modify your project paths.

Given that you mention that you have almost one directory per `.py` file, you should also consider how your code might be organized into [packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) to further simplify your setup.

Comment: Actually, my `bash` way that I've mentioned above is (kind of) an `init` script. I usually `export` and `source` the `bashrc` before calling a `python` process (I'm developing via a ssh connection to a server, which cant be turned off as my wish). By this time, while everyone say that this is not good practice (and I do feel so, not sure why, so I bring it up here for a clarification), but I still can't see any bad effects for my project. Although, since I didn't mention `bashrc` and this is actually a very simple and effective way, your answer worth being accepted :D Thank you very much

Answer (score -3):

It's not a particularly good practice, though you could get away with it. Better to look into virtualenv though (or pipenv) for a smoother workflow.

Comment: I do use virtualenv for every projects of mine, what I mean here is not `import` a pypi package, but my own package from other directory (but same project) of mine.

Comment: It's the same whether you're using a package from pypi, or your own package. Install them properly (and if they're not packages, they should be!).