# Import module from parent directory in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have python script in following directory structure

```
common/
    log.py
    file.py
    __init__.py
     conf/
        myconf.py
       
        __init__.py
```

here is my myconf.py

```
from common import file

data = file.myfunction()
print (data )
```

here is file.py

```
import log

myfunction():

return "dummy"
```

when i run my `myconf.py` i get below error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'log`

how to handle import `log` in my  `myconf.py`?

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to add `common` to your `PYTHONPATH` and run everything from there. This is the best practice and the best solution in my opinion to handle the imports.

To do so:

1. In terminal, cd to the directory where common directory is there.
2. Run `export PYTHONPATH=${PWD}`
3. Change your imports to start from common, for example:

```
from common import log
```

```
from common import file
```

```
from common.conf.myconf import something
```

4. If you want to run a file, run it from the root:

```
python common/conf/myconf.py
```

This way you will never have any import error and all your imports are extremely clear and readable cause they all start from `common`

Comment: How is it don't work in a long run? You rarely rebuild a whole project structure deep in. That's how I organize imports in every python project I work on. You usually have a root source directory, set it to PYTHONPATH and then all imports are related to the root. Btw you can run your code `python -m common.conf.myconf` and you then don't need to use PYTHONPATH

Comment: I meant to put this comment on the solution below this. Made a mistake and actually commented on my own answer :)) I'll delete it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run `myconf.py` as the entry point from anywhere without caring about `PYTHONPATH` you can add the parent folder of `common` to `sys.path`.

myconf.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys; from os.path import dirname
    sys.path.append(dirname(dirname(dirname(__file__))))

from common import file

data = file.myfunction()
print(data)
```

log.py

```
from common import log

def myfunction():
    return "dummy"
```

Comment: Manipulating `sys.path` is not a good practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146723/is-adding-project-root-directory-to-sys-path-a-good-practice#:~:text=It%20is%20generally%20not%20good,%3A%24PYTHONPATH%22%20python%20...