# Any alternative to the typical ModuleNotFoundError: No module named when using Pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, modulenotfounderror

I have spent a fair amount of time in order to find a solution to this kind of "typical" issue when using pytest. Thus, even though it may look the same, I have not been able to fix using these common solutions and that is why I do not think this is duplicated.

I have the following structure:

[image]

In test_logic.py I make use of:

```
from backend.api.logic import my_class
```

When I run my test using the "test tab" on the left-hand side of VSCode, it works perfectly fine.

However, in order to do automate my test, formatting and so on I have a bat file where I do:

```
pytest --cov . test/
```

In the past it worked ok, up until now, where now it takes into account the my_class import.
I cannot get it to work anymore. I try adding `__init__.py` literally everywhere and even adding the project path to sys.path in the `logic_test.py` file:

```
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
project_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, "../..")
sys.path.append(project_dir)
```

However, I still get:

```
============================================================================= test session starts =============================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.5, pytest-7.4.3, pluggy-1.3.0
rootdir: C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\PROJECTS\PROJECT
plugins: cov-4.1.0
collected 0 items / 1 error

=================================================================================== ERRORS ====================================================================================
__________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/backend/api/tlogic_test.py ___________________________________________________________ 
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\PROJECTS\PROJECT\tests\backend\api\logic.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests\backend\api\logic.py:7: in <module>
    from backend.api.logic import my_class
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend'
```

Pretty sure I am missing something super simple or even something I have double-checked already but I cant get to sort it out!

**-------EDIT------**

I managed to get it sorted. I got the idea from:

[Is adding project root directory to sys.path a good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146723/is-adding-project-root-directory-to-sys-path-a-good-practice)

and added my project directory dynamically inside the bat file that I am using to run the tests (originally I tried adding the directory to the PYTHONPATH from the script file).

Comment: You're just executing it from the wrong directory. `C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\PROJECTS\PROJECT`, `C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\PROJECTS\PORTFOLIO`…?! Your working directory should be `proyect`, according to your initial directory listing.

Comment: Sorry, a typo mistake when copying it. It is indeed ..\PROJECT. I haved modified it.
Anyway, I found the solution!

Answer (score 0):

As per my edited question (bottom of it), I simply added this to the top of my bat file:

```
@echo off
set "PROYECT_PATH=%~dp0"
set "PYTHONPATH=%PROYECT_PATH%;%PYTHONPATH%"
```